# Online Weapon Progress

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I've recently started getting back into *Battlefield : Bad Company 2*, and stumbled upon a problem I recall having back when I used to play the game more:

#### Where can I check my medal progress?

I noticed that in certain kill cams, you can see the weapon used to kill you, as well as a corresponding *'rank'* associated with the weapon (represented by a little star beside the weapon), which I believe to be dictated by the number of gold stars gotten with the weapon. This led me to wanting to see the *'ranks'* of my own weapons, and what others might see when I kill them. So if these stars are dictated by gold stars achieved with the weapon, where can I check my own gold stars earned, as well as any pending progress with my weapons?

To clarify a bit: when I say medal progress, I am referring to the medals that require a certain threshold to be met (x number of kills before my next gold star, weapon efficiency pins, etc) before being awarded, as well as any other related medals that require playing to progress. I've checked the *Progress* tab after the end of a round, but since I've already unlocked all weapons with all classes, this tab displays nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on PC, navigating to the Multiplayer -> My Stats menu (shown below) will take you to a login prompt, after which it will show you your profile.

[image: Main Menu, Battlefield Bad Company 2]

After this, you select Awards to show progress in Medals and Ribbons.

[image: Awards, Profile, Battlefield Bad Company 2]

I'm afraid I can't easily confirm this on a console, but I assume that it will be available in the same way.